# Custom Tool is not added in my Form design if I pull it from Tool Box - VS C#

Tags: c#, custom-controls, windows-forms-designer

#### Library File

```
namespace Library1 {
   public class AlphaTextBox : TextBox { 
       protected override void OnKeyPress( KeyPressEventArgs e ) {
           base.OnKeyPress(e);
           if( !Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) ) {
             MessageBox.Show("Non-alpha character is pressed !");
           }
       }
    }
}
```

From choose *Choose ToolBox Item* I added Library1.dll, and when I tried to Click and Drag its not added in Form Design.

But I did like this some days back, It worked fine. Whats the problem here? How can I make it to add in my windows form project.

Comment: What may be the reason? It is added in toolbox. But not added in Form design. I tried closing and reopening and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally it should get added. If it is not then re-open your application and try again. Another way is to add it at runtime through code.

Comment: You can add it in designer.cs also...dont forget to add Library1 namespace